# Set value when textarea has changed but focus has not been lost

Tags: javascript

When users change a textarea I use onchange to set a lock value. If they submit the change it clears the lock, but if the try to close or refresh the page or exit out of the form then my site will send an alert to let them know they are about to lose their changes.

```
 <textarea onchange="lock=1"></textarea>
```

Unfortunately, onchange only fires when a change has been made AND when the user blurs the text field.

Currently, if a person has made changes but have not yet submitted them and the textarea is still in focus, they will lose their changes if F5 is accidentally pressed.

I was thinking of using onkeypress but there's lot of times when the person might be pressing keys in the form and it not result in a change, like cursor keys.

Is there a way to set a value if the contents has changed, even if the field hasn't been blured yet?

Comment: Where is your code ? HTML, JS to help with correct answer

Comment: @AlwaysHelping all I'm currently using to set the value is the inline code above.